# DOB validation with moment js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to satisfy a business logic, where a user is validated if he or she is 100 years or younger. I am using moment js to calculate the years of difference based on a DOB input. The following is my logic

```
let isValidDate = true;
const maxAge = 100;
const years = moment().diff(moment(dateVal, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'years', true);

if (years > maxAge) {
  isValidDate = false;
}
.......
```

With the current logic of moment i have the value returns a floating point value. For instance if I enter in **11/2/1919** returns 100.003, which validates the date false, when I want it to be true. If I change the last parameter in `diff()` to **false**, it will evaluate to 100 but this will also evaluate **1/1/1919** to 100.

Is there a better way of handling this use case?

Comment: What exactly is your base date value you are trying to get the distance to here? Sounds like you might simply have a problem with two dates with different hours of the day …

Comment: not sure what you mean by base date value, the dateVal variable is what the user enters in

Comment: I meant the other one … if you are using just `moment()`, that is probably simply today’s date with the hours/min/sec set to whatever “now” is? So use the current date, but with the time component set to `00:00:00`.

Comment: The format you specify (YYYY-MM-DD) isn't same as the format of dateVal which is 11/2/1919. Try changing the format to `MM/DD/YYYY`. The following code works for me `let dateVal = '02/09/1919'
let isValidDate = true;
const maxAge = 100;
const years = moment().diff(moment(dateVal, 'MM/DD/YYYY'), 'years', true);

console.log(years > maxAge);
if (years > maxAge) {
  isValidDate = false;
}`

Answer (score 3):

Instead of computing the number of years elapsed (which can give you fractional results), simply add the number of years desired and check if the result is in range.

```
// The birth date - be sure to parse in the same format you're expecting:
const dob = moment("11/2/1919", "D/M/YYYY");

// The constant number of years you don't want to exceed
const maxAge = 100;

//  Clone the dob (to not mutate it), increment by the years, and compare with day precision
const isValidDate = dob.clone().add(maxAge, 'years').isSameOrBefore(moment(), 'day');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
validateDobWithMoment(dob) {
  const maxAge = 120;
  const minAge = 0;
  const mDobDate = moment(dob);
  const mCurrDate = moment();
  const age = mCurrDate.diff(mDobDate, 'years');
  if (parseInt(age) > minAge && parseInt(age) < maxAge) {
    // dob is valid
    return true;
  } else {
    // dob not valid
    return false;
  }
};
```